# Получение 2 параметров из <datalist>

Tags: php, json, steam-web-api, datalist

Получаю список игр Steam следующим образом:

```
<input type="text" name="gamename" class="form-control" list="gameselect" data-placeholder="Найдите игру" style="width: 100%;" required>
<datalist id="gameselect">
<?php
$json="http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2";
$url = file_get_contents("$json") ;
$data = json_decode($url)->applist;
foreach ($data->apps as $item) {
    echo "<option name='appid' id=" . $item->appid .">" . $item->name . "</option>";
}
?>
```

В итоге, через `input` получаю только название игры. Мне же нужно еще и `appid` перенести через `POST`, чтобы дальше делать уже другие операции с этим же API. Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Comment: Проще найти appid по названию.
А если пользователь поменяет название игры?

Comment: "$json" - уберите кавычки

Comment: Я так и не понял, в чём проблема и что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @n.osennij с кавычками все хорошо. Из `datalist` в `input` заносится только название игры, а `id` нет. В этом и вопрос, как и куда занести `id`, чтобы передать его обработчику вместе с названием игры?

Comment: А обработчик вы сами пишете?

Comment: Само собой. Не понятно, какое это имеет отношение к вопросу, на самом деле :)

Comment: У Ваших `option`ов нет свойства `value`, поэтому Вам приходит только название. Добавьте этот атрибут (значение - `id` игры), а на сервере проверяйте по `id` наличие в массиве, как Вам подсказали в ответе

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно 2 параметра. appid соответствует названию игры.

Ваш select может выглядеть так:

```
<select name="appid">
  <?php foreach($gameData as $appid => $gameName):?>
    <option value="<?=$appid?>"><?=$gameName?></option>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

На серверной стороне у вас должен быть массив соответствий ($gameData).
Он будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
$gameData = [
  730 => 'CS:GO',
  440 => 'TF2',
  570 => 'Dota2',
];
```

Данные для этого массива можно взять, например, [здась](https://steamdb.info/apps/)